# Trying to find the field 'Search Query' from GA in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to find the Google Analytics field 'Search Query' in BigQuery. I can find 'keyword', but not the 'Search Query'.

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere!

Comment: Do you mean the query of an on site search, or the keyword the user googled to reach the site?

Comment: The search query that was typed in in Google to reach the site (mainly AdWords)

Answer (score 2):

`trafficSource.keyword` is the field you need, as per the [export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en):

```
    trafficSource.keyword   
    STRING  
    The keyword of the traffic source, usually set when the trafficSource.medium 
    is "organic" or "cpc". Can be set by the utm_term URL parameter.
```

Comment: TrafficSource.keyword, which returns the keyword, but I'm looking for the Search Query (or Search term).


For example: I search on Google for 'yellow raincoat sale', so that's my search query. When I click on the ad, the keyword is '+yellow +raincoat'. I want to find the search query. In the GA interface you can find this under the field 'Search Query', but there seems to be no such field in BigQuery.

Comment: Oops yes you are right, will correct my post now. Edit further your comment: Aha, got you, you'll have to looking Google Search Console for the query data, I don't believe this is in BigQuery.

Comment: When selecting 'trafficSource.keyword' all I get in return is the Google AdWords(Ads) keyword & not the search query. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I'm looking for AdWords search terms though

Comment: You can transfer this data into BigQuery with Google Ads Transfers: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181289/discussion-between-user3457337-and-ben-p).