# Trying to find the field 'Search Query' from GA in BigQuery v2

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-ads-api, google-ads-data-hub

This is a follow up to the question that @user3457337 posted here: [Trying to find the field 'Search Query' from GA in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647133/trying-to-find-the-field-search-query-from-ga-in-bigquery).

My question is exactly the same as theirs. Does anyone know if you ingest both Google Ads (previously adwords) data and google analytics data into Bigquery if there is a way to get the user level search queries? I went through the schemas of both and can't seem to find a way to do this for the life of me given the issues that @user3457337 ran into. Any help would be sincerely appreciated! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to find the field 'Search Query' from GA in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647133/trying-to-find-the-field-search-query-from-ga-in-bigquery)

Comment: Hi @Carl K. Unfortunately, the question was never fully answered. :( I even checked their chat record but was never able to find the answer of how to associate the raw GA user data in bigquery to the raw Google Ads search query data.